# Can anyone explain this quote from Max to me?

Tags: max-payne-3

Spoilers on the last mission.

When Max was about to execute Becker, I realize that cutscene at the start of the game was a flashforward in the game. Max seems to be talking about someone or some people on this quote, I highlighted the words I don't know who is Max referring to. Max says:

> So I guess I'd become what **they**(1) wanted me to be, a killer. Some rent-a-clown with a gun who puts holes in other bad guys. Well that's what **they**(2) had paid for, so in the end that's what they got. Say what you want about Americans but we understand capitalism. You buy yourself a product and you get what you pay for, and **these chumps**(3) had paid for some angry gringo without the sensibilities to know right from wrong. Here I was about to execute this poor bastard like some dime store angel of death and I realized **they were correct**(4), I wouldn't know right from wrong if one of **them**(5) was helping the poor and the other was banging my sister...

1. Who are they?
2. Same question.
3. Who are the chumps? Rodrigo?
4. Who are they and what were they correct about?
5. One of them who?

Sorry for bringing this here, but English is not the primary language on my country, so I don't know it that good, so this may be why I didn't get this quote.

Answer (score 2):

1. they in this case is victor bronco and the people he was using to betray his brothers.
2. Same answer
3. Chumps is the same again, victor had paid pasos to get max pain from America
4. They is once again the people who had bought max.
5. One of them is referring to right and wrong, he is explaining that he dominoes know the difference between them.

Hope this helps.